# Toggling Property Does Not Show Change in Real Time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, boolean, ibaction

I have a star button that I want to toggle between filled and empty when tapping. [image]

I implemented the following function:

```
func setStarButton() {
        
        let currentItem = data[currentItemIndex!]
        if currentItem.isStarred == true {
            starButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            starButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }

@IBAction func starTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        // Change the property in the Array
        var currentItem = item[currentItemIndex!]
        currentItem.isStarred?.toggle()
        
        // Update the database
        model.updateStarredStatus(currentItem.docID!, currentItem.isStarred!)
        
        // Update the button
        setStarButton()
        
    }
```

I am then calling that function in the viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        // Set the status of the star button
        setStarButton()
        
    }
```

So the following expected behaviour is happening:

1. The star button is showing as the correct filled/unfilled status only when I open the view controller for the first time
2. When I tap the star button, my Firebase Firestore database updates the Bool value

What I am trying to make happen: for the star button to become filled/unfilled in the view as I continue to tap it in real time.

Any thoughts? I'm think I might need the view to listen for changes in the database to make visual update but I'm not sure. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Are the items in your array classes or structs?

Comment: @Paulw11 They are structs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `item` array contains structs.  Structs in Swift are value types.  You effectively assign a copy of the struct to `currentItem` when you say `var currentItem = item[currentItemIndex!]`. This copy is then modified and thrown away when the function returns.

Later, when you access `data[currentItemIndex!]` in `setStarButton` you are accessing the original, unmodified struct.  After you refresh the array from Firebase you see the correct value.

A simple way to avoid the problem is just to eliminate the local variable `currentItem` and operate on the struct in the array directly.

Personally, I would rater pass the relevant value to `setStarred`; that way you eliminate the duplicated code of access the items array.  You should also avoid force unwrapping wherever possible. It also doesn't make a lot of sense for properties like `isStarred` and `docID` to be optional - An item is either starred or it isn't.  A default value of `false` makes more sense than `nil`.  All documents from Firebase will have a `docID`

```
func setStarButton(starred: Bool) {
     
    let imageName = starred ? "star.fill" : "star"

    starButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: imageName), for: .normal)
 
}

@IBAction func starTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard itemIndex = self.currentItemIndex else {
        return
    }

    var isStarred = item[itemIndex].isStarred ?? false

    isStarred.toggle()
    item[itemIndex].isStarred = isStarred
        
        // Update the database
    model.updateStarredStatus(currentItem.docID!, isStarred)
        
        // Update the button
    setStarButton(starred: isStarred)
        
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Set the status of the star button
    if let itemIndex = self.currentItemIndex {
        setStarButton(starred: self.item[itemIndex].isStarred ?? false)
    } 
}
```

Comment: This was a perfect explanation. The assigning of data was my knowledge gap, and your other points were great tips to optimize my code. Thank you so much!